# Combine two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query that is returning two rows of data that I would like to combine into 1. It is returning two rows because there is two `PYMNT_TYPES` associated with the `VOUCHER`.

I would like to add some kind of logic where if the `PYMNT_TYPE` is equal to "W" then I want the `PYMNT_GROSS_AMT` to be it's own field called `WITHHOLDING_AMT` to eliminate the 2nd row.

The part I am struggling with is that there are other columns that that have different values on each row and I'm not sure whether the above change would eliminate the 2nd row?

The only information I care about on the 2nd row that is not on the first row is the `PYMNT_GROSS_AMT` that has it's unique value from what is on the first row. This is why I am trying to combine the rows.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF
  WHERE VOUCHER_ID = '00026130'
  AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
```

Data being returned now:
[image]

**EDITED CODE:**

```
   SELECT 
    T1.*
   ,T2.PYMNT_GROSS_AMT 
 FROM 
    PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF T1
 LEFT JOIN
    PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF T2 on
    T2.VOUCHER_ID = T1.VOUCHER_ID AND T2.BUSINESS_UNIT = T1.BUSINESS_UNIT 
    AND T2.PYMNT_TYPE = 'W' 
 WHERE 
    T1.VOUCHER_ID = '00026130'
    AND T1.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join seems to be what you want

```
 SELECT 
    T1.*
   ,T2.PYMNT_GROSS_AMT 
 FROM 
    PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF T1
 LEFT JOIN
    PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF T2 on
    T2.VOUCHER_ID = T1.VOUCHER_ID  --or what ever the join condition should be
    T2.PYMNT_TYPE ='W'
 WHERE 
    T1.VOUCHER_ID = '00026130'
    AND T1.BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
    and T1.PYMNT_TYPE != 'W'
```

Comment: I added the edited code above based on your suggestion, however I am still returning 2 rows. Any ideas?

Comment: you forgot the bottom part... `where .... and T1.PYMNT_TYPE != 'W'` you'll see this in my answer.

Comment: Your right! Awesome thanks! Thought maybe it was going to involve using some kind of pivot functions but this is more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you could do:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT PYMNT_GROSS_AMT FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF 
        WHERE VOUCHER_ID = p.VOUCHER_ID 
        AND BUSINESS_UNIT = p.BUSINESS_UNIT
        AND PYMNT_TYPES = 'W') WITHHOLDING_AMT
FROM PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF p
WHERE PYMNT_TYPES = 'R'
--optional conditions
AND VOUCHER_ID = '00026130'
AND BUSINESS_UNIT = '50000'
```